# Using <br> together with display: inline-block. Bad practice?

Tags: html, css

I'm using a form like the following:

```
<form action="#" method="post">

  <div class="row">
    <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <br>
    <label for="passwordRepeat">Repeat Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="passwordRepeat" id="passwordRepeat">
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="phonenumber">Phone Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber">
  </div>

</form>
```

with the following styles:

```
.row {
  background-color: #eee;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.row > * {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.row > label {
    width: 200px;
}
```

Take a look at the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pwtA4/).

I'm using a `<br>` tag to break the line between a bunch of elements with the property `display: inline-block`. I'm aware that it is of course bad practice to use `<br>` instead of margin and padding. That's the reason it became so unpopular.

As far as I know there is no good reason to not use a single `<br>` tag in an inline element as it is intended to be: As a line break in text without creating a new text section. With `display: inline-block`, you simulate the inline behaviour to your block elements. Spaces between elements appear as they would in an inline element.
In my case, the `<br>` is used instead of two wrapper `<div>`'s. I do like my HTML code clean, so I hesitate in using to many wrapper `<div>`'s. Is it bad practice to use a `<br>` in this exact case? I think it is very clear what happens here, if you just read the HTML flie. What do you think about that (without any prejudgments about `<br>` in general)?

Comment: Hi @peter. Personally I think your use of `<br>` here is fine. But I see the argument against ( but those that argue against your use of it here , must really be nit picking ) - fwiw - the the same can be achieved by setting adding css to cause the 'break' `{ margin-bottom:0.5em; }` / or similar . That's what good about `inline-block` elements hey, the behave like `inline` elements but take margins and paddings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is **Yes**. `<br />` is for line breaks in text and not for positioning, But I will give you a situation where it would hurt you in the long run. Say you have a mobile layout for your fields, and you want them to be 100% width on small screens - with labels above... and then in another case you want them to vertically align next to another... and then in another situation land in a grid like setup. Those linebreaks are going to become cumbersome.

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/X8U3e/) of that.

*I did see* someone using them in a clever way where they used `display: none;` on them at certain break points that rendered them inactive. I didn't expect that to work. I can only really imagine using them for:

Cosmo magazine
style - huge
text layouts

and even then I would use lettering.js to insert spans. But hey --- it's not that people will say you were wrong... it's what does the job best. And I don't think that `<br />` ever really suits positioning.

With HTML5, it seems like everything has an element now, so div's are for positioning. That seems pretty semantic to me.

### HTML

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <label data-required="required">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" />
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.your-form .input-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.your-form label {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

[data-required="required"]:after{
    content: "*";
    color: red;
    font-size: .8em;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding: .2em;
}

.your-form input{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 28em) {

    .your-form label {
        width: auto;
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        min-width: 10em;
    }

    .your-form input{
        width: auto; /* overide previous rule */
        float: none; /* overide previous rule */
        display: inline-block; /* center vertically */
        vertical-align: middle; /* center vertically */
        /* min-width: 20em; */
        font-size: 1.4em; /* just to show vertical align */
    }

} /* end break point */
```

Comment: This would all be flexbox or grid now ^

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you are using a content element for styling.
It might be shorter, but that doesn't mean it's cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Adding elements just for styling purposes should be avoided if possible.

And in this case it's possible: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/pwtA4/1/)

HTML:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
    <div class="row">
        <label>E-Mail <input type="text" name="email" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Password <input type="password" name="password" /></label>
        <label>Repeat Password <input type="password" name="passwordRepeat" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <label>Phone Number <input type="text" name="phonenumber" /></label>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    background-color: #eee;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 5px;
}
.row > label {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 350px;
}
.row > label > input {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid it where possible. You may be able to achive what you want, and not use floats by adding a margin to the `input` element like:

```
.row > input
{
    margin-right:50%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pwtA4/

You may need to add some [media queries](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) if you want for smaller view ports